# Disable too-many-ifs heuristic

Tags: acl2

How do I disable the too-many-ifs heuristic?  Sometimes the prover goes out to lunch, and when I interrupt it, I can see that the prover is busy with a call of `too-many-ifs0` and `count-ifs-lst`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the too-many-ifs heuristic into an effective no-op by issuing the following forms.  Note that if you're using these in a book, you probably want to make each of the below forms "local":

```
(defn too-many-ifs-pre-rewrite-noop (args counts)
  (declare (ignore args counts))
  nil)

(defattach too-many-ifs-pre-rewrite too-many-ifs-pre-rewrite-noop)

(defn too-many-ifs-post-rewrite-noop (args counts)
  (declare (ignore args counts))
  nil)

(defattach too-many-ifs-post-rewrite too-many-ifs-post-rewrite-noop)
```